# Eventos que no se disparan porque son nulos aun despues de asignarlos

Tags: c#

En la siguiente clase de ejemplo, se crea un objeto con una coleccion observable y se llena por defecto, asignando a cada clase de sus elementos un evento.

Sin embargo, al hacer un cambio sobre los elementos, estos no saben cual es el listener del evento y no lo disparan. A que puede deberse?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RestriccionVM restriccionVM = new RestriccionVM();
        Console.WriteLine("inicia");
        Console.WriteLine("deberia mostrar 1");
        restriccionVM.ListaSistema[0].Chequeado = true;
        Console.WriteLine("deberia haberse visto 1");
        Console.WriteLine("deberia mostrar 1,2");
        restriccionVM.ListaSistema[1].Chequeado = true;
        Console.WriteLine("deberia haberse visto 1,2");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public class RestriccionVM 
    {


        public ObservableCollection<ObjetosParaListview> ListaSistema
        {
            get;
            set;

        }


        #region contructores

        public RestriccionVM()
        {
            ObjetosParaListview ObjetoTemporal;
            ListaSistema = new ObservableCollection<ObjetosParaListview>();
            ObjetoTemporal = new ObjetosParaListview { Chequeado = false, Texto = "1" };
            ObjetoTemporal.CambioUnCheck += HacerCambioDeCheck();
            ListaSistema.Add(ObjetoTemporal);
            ObjetoTemporal = new ObjetosParaListview { Chequeado = false, Texto = "2" };
            ObjetoTemporal.CambioUnCheck += HacerCambioDeCheck();
            ListaSistema.Add(ObjetoTemporal);
            ObjetoTemporal = new ObjetosParaListview { Chequeado = false, Texto = "3" };
            ObjetoTemporal.CambioUnCheck += HacerCambioDeCheck();
            ListaSistema.Add(ObjetoTemporal);
        }

        #endregion

        public Action HacerCambioDeCheck()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("entro al evento");
            List<string> lista = new List<string>();
            foreach (ObjetosParaListview o in ListaSistema)
            {
                if (o.Chequeado)
                {
                    lista.Add(o.Texto);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", lista));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ObjetosParaListview
    {

        public event Action CambioUnCheck;

        private bool _Chequeado;
        public bool Chequeado
        {
            get
            {
                return _Chequeado;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!_Chequeado.Equals(value))
                {
                    _Chequeado = value;
                    CambioUnCheck?.Invoke();
                    Console.WriteLine("cambio");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _Texto;
        public string Texto
        {
            get
            {
                return _Texto;
            }
            set
            {
                _Texto = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está con las sentencias donde le asignas el event handler:

```
ObjetoTemporal.CambioUnCheck += HacerCambioDeCheck();
```

En vez de asignarle una referencia al método `HacerCambioDeCheck`, que es tu intención, le estás asignando el *resultado* devuelto por la ejecución del método, o sea `null`.

La asignación debería ser:

```
ObjetoTemporal.CambioUnCheck += HacerCambioDeCheck; // sin las paréntesis
```

Y esto, a su vez implica que debes modificar el método `HacerCambioDeCheck` para que sea con return type `void`:

```
public void HacerCambioDeCheck()
{
    ...
    // return null;
}
```