# Problema con implementación de eventos en una interface vb Net

Tags: vb.net, eventos, interface

Antes de explicar y detallar cuál es mi problema, quisiera aclarar (al final lo haré) que tengo una manera de hacerlo pero no es lo que requiero. Me gustaría poder aprender exactamente lo que busco saber.

Bien, tengo en una libreria (dll) la siguiente interface:

```
Public Interface ICompatible
    Event ShowSplashScreen(ByVal strMessage As String)
    Event HideSplashScreen()
    Sub OnShowSplashScreen(ByVal strMessage As String)
    Sub OnHiddeSplashScreen()
End Interface
```

En esa misma libreria (proyecto) tengo una clase que implementa dicha interface de la siguiente manera:

```
Public Class VastiSplashScreen
    Implements ICompatible

    Private frm As New frmSplashScreen()

    Public Event HideSplashScreen() Implements ICompatible.HideSplashScreen
    Private Event ShowSplashScreen(strMessage As String) Implements ICompatible.ShowSplashScreen


    Public Sub OnShowSplashScreen(strMessage As String) Implements ICompatible.OnShowSplashScreen
        RaiseEvent ShowSplashScreen(strMessage)
        frm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub   
    Public Sub OnHiddeSplashScreen() Implements ICompatible.OnHiddeSplashScreen
        RaiseEvent HideSplashScreen()
        frm.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Como pueden ver, está implementada y calificada la interface. Ahora los métodos son los que disparan (pero aún no se si eso es correcto) los eventos, pero lo que pretendo es lo siguiente:

***En otro proyecto*** importo esta librería que acabo de exponer en un UserControl de la siguiente manera:

```
Imports SALLATNAP01
Public Class UC_Embolse
    Implements ICompatible

    Public Event ShowSplashScreen As ICompatible.ShowSplashScreenEventHandler Implements ICompatible.ShowSplashScreen
    Public Event HideSplashScreen As ICompatible.HideSplashScreenEventHandler Implements ICompatible.HideSplashScreen

    Public Sub OnShowSplashScreen(strMessage As String) Implements ICompatible.OnShowSplashScreen
        RaiseEvent ShowSplashScreen(strMessage)
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnHiddeSplashScreen() Implements ICompatible.OnHiddeSplashScreen
        RaiseEvent HideSplashScreen()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OnShowSplashScreen("este es un ejemplo")       
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        OnHiddeSplashScreen()
    End Sub    
End Class
```

Ahora si, explico lo que sucede aqui, implemento dicha interface y lo que pretendo es que mediante algún evento de click como en este ejemplo que es un boton simple, yo pueda ejecutar el evento *ShowSplashScreen* el cual obviamente está siendo disparado desde la libreria *SALLATNAP01* que lo que hace o más bien ***debería*** estar haciendo es abriendo el formulario ***frm*** pasandole como parámetro alguna leyenda que en dicho formulario (ventana modal) debería poder ser capaz de ver el usuario.

No tengo ningún error en ejecución, pero no hace nada el programa.

***Ahora bien*** tengo una forma de hacerlo pero no es lo que requiero y es esta:

En la clase VastiSplashScreen de la librería si yo pongo el siguiente método:

```
Private Sub HandleTimeExpired(strMensaje As String) Handles Me.ShowSplashScreen
        MiSingleton.MensajeSplashScreen = strMensaje
        frm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

Y en el UserControl hago una instancia de esa clase de esta forma:

```
Private instancia as new VastiSplashScreen
```

Y pongo la siguiente instrucción en algún lado digamos en el evento clic del boton así:

```
instancia.HandleTimeExpired("cualquier mensaje")
```

Si lo hace, abre al final de cuentas el *frm* que necesito con la leyenda que le paso como parámetro pero no siento ni percibo que estoy haciendo uso entonces de eventos controlados por una interface.

Espero que alguién pueda apoyarme, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Falta algo re importante aca, y es quien recibe y ejecuta dichos eventos? o sea, un evento es solo la definicion de una funcion, pero alguien tiene que escribir el cuerpo del evento y conectar dicha funcion a ese cuerpo....

Comment: Fijate si esta pregunta no te ilumina https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114321/324

Comment: @gbianchi me quede más perdido jaja, no entendí..

Comment: @gbianchi espera me estas queriendo decir que quite el paréntesis de la instancia que hago del formulario?, haber deja hago una prueba jaja xD

Comment: @gbianchi no mi hermano, sigo sin tener resultados =(.. seguiré tratando por mi cuenta..

Comment: No. Intenta el ejemplo de esa pregunta. Aca por mas que definis un evento, nunca definis que hacer cuando ocurre el evento. Creo que tu confusion viene de lo que es un evento. Si te pasas por el [chat] podremos explicarte

Comment: @gbianchi no le entiendo al chat, como puedo hacerle?